# In Z notation, how to define a division operation for integer numbers

Tags: z-notation

I was wondering to know if anyone out here even used the "Z notation" in a professional environment.
Just curious to know some commonly-known applications of Z or your application.

For those who are not familiar : http://staff.washington.edu/jon/z/z-examples.html

I want to know "In Z notation, how to define a division operation for integer numbers"

Answer (score 0):

The integer division is already part of Z's mathematical toolkit:

```
a \div b
```

(See the [Z manual by M. Spivey](http://spivey.oriel.ox.ac.uk/mike/zrm/), chapter 4.4 Numbers and Finiteness)